# When cloning a draggable object in jQuery UI, how can you transfer the data and events to the new element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, clone, draggable

I have a draggable element with the `helper: 'clone'` set, but when it clones the element, none of the `data()` or events are persistent in the new element.

I've tried a number of ways to reattach the `data()`, but I can't seem to select the new element as well as the old element in the same statement.

For instance, I can select the initial element in the draggable `stop()` event:

```
$blah.draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    stop: function(ev, ui) {
        var oldData = $(ev.target).data('blah');
    }
});
```

And I can also get the new element in the droppable `drop()` event:

```
$blah.droppable({
    drop : function(ev, ui) {
        var $newElement = ui.draggable;
    }
});
```

But I can't figure out a way to get both in the same event.

What I'd like to do is somehow transfer the data, e.g.:

```
$newElement.data('blah', $oldElement.data('blah'));
```

Or otherwise make the data persistent, like you can with `$blah.clone(true);`

Answer (score 14):

To get access to the data of original element in drop you can use ui.draggable.context. In the example below context would refer to the original dragged element and you have access to all of its content. Draggable refers to the new element that is being dropped.

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {        
        console.log(ui);
        console.log(ui.draggable.context);
        console.log($(ui.draggable.context).data('pic'));
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm answering this 4 years after it was posted and perhaps the api has changed (I'm using JqueryUI 1.11), but I'm not seeing a `ui.draggable` property, as mentioned here.  However, I did find a reference to the original container of my dragged object through `$(e.currentTarget.activeElement).closest("#my_container")`.  There isn't a `ui.draggable.context`, but rather a `ui.helper.context`.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked too extensively with droppable, but couldn't you just do something like this?

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});

$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone(true));
    }
});
```

Seems to work unless there's something I'm missing:

http://jsfiddle.net/hasrq/

Comment: Re-read your question, `ui.draggable` does not appear to be the new element as you mentioned but rather the original.

Comment: Hey this really put me on the right track, because it turns out the issue was that I was combining it with sortable() which is where the problem actually arose.  Posting my solution below.  But thanks a bunch for your help on this one!

Comment: Well if you're using sortable this may be helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788391/jquery-how-to-update-draggable-clone-id/5864644#5864644

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was sortable, not draggable / droppable (I was attaching sortable later on, but figured it wasn't part of the problem here so I left it out of the original question).

I ended up using sort of a combination of @kingjiv's solution above, along with a not-the-greatest hack but at least it seems to be working:

```
$blah.sortable({
    receive: function(ev, ui) {
        // setting a global variable here
        MyGlobals.cloneCache = ui.item.clone(true);
    },
    stop: function(ev, ui) {
        $(ui.item).replaceWith(MyGlobals.cloneCache);
    }
});
```

The idea is that you first clone the original item in the `receive()` event, cache this in a variable, and then replace the item with that in the `stop()` event.

Kind of ugly but at least it's working.

Comment: Actually this had other problems, since when you tried to drag to re-sort, it pulled from the original element, ugh.  So now I have a really horrid hack in place where I cache the data I need in the receive, then apply it in the stop, but only if another piece of 'isChanged' data hasn't been applied yet (or else the cache gets called and messes up the data on re-sort)...super ugly but working afaik

Comment: I'm getting the same type of issue. Could you please post the code which solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

`ui.item` refers to dragged item. When the dragged item is cloned, there is no built-in way to access the target item from `receive` function. However, there is a bit hacky way how to do it:

```
$blah.sortable({
    receive: function (ev, ui) {
        var $target = $(this).data().sortable.currentItem;
        var $source = $(ui.sender);
        // now you can copy data from source to target
        $target.data('data-item', $source.data('data-item')); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: In recent version of jquery-ui you can access the target item via `ui.helper`