# jQuery UI draggable+sortable keep draggable's css

Tags: css, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

When using jQuery UI draggable+sortable the draggable element loses it's css when dropped into sortable. Here's my code and here's a [js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y6KHn/1/)

Try to put the draggable div into sortable and see that it loses it's  (in this case) background-color and border. Is it possible to prevent this?

```
<script>
    $("#content").sortable({
        revert:true
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#content",
      revert: "invalid",
      stop: function(event,ui) {
        $(ui.item).attr('id','draggable');
      }
    });
</script>
<style>
 #content {width:150px;}
 #draggable {   
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:blue;} 
 .text {
    min-height:100px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;

    background-color:red;
 }
</style>
<div id="content">
    <div class="text">Item</div>
    <div class="text">Item</div>
    <div class="text">Item</div>
    <div class="text">Item</div>
    <div class="text">Item</div>
    <div class="text">Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This behavior can be avoided using `helper:"clone"` or a function that returns domElement that will be used while dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if you need the ID for other things, you can add this code to your sortable call:

```
  beforeStop: function (event, ui) { 
      newItem = ui.item;
  },
  receive: function(event,ui) {
      $(newItem).attr("id","draggable");     
  }
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y6KHn/5/

see [jquery: how to update draggable clone id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788391/jquery-how-to-update-draggable-clone-id)

Answer (score 0):

The ID will be lost by dragging.  You can get around this by attaching the css to a class instead.
In your html:

```
<div id="draggable" class="dragclass">Drag</div>
```

and in the css:

```
 .dragclass {   
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:blue;}
```

see updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/y6KHn/2/

Comment: Drag the element on the sortable area and then somewhere outside it. Then drop it. The element doesn't return to it's initial state.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - it keeps its style and class.  Are you talking about the sortable list shifting up?