# Draggable connected to sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to be able to drag items from one Infragistics DataGrid to another, while the items in the Destination grid are also sortable.

Unfortunately, I cannot use jsfiddle because I cannot use the infragistics controls there.

```
$("[id*=sourceGrid] [id*=dataTbl] tbody tr").draggable({
   helper: "clone",
   revert: "invalid",
   connectToSortable: '[id*=destination]'                   
});

$("[id*=destinationGrid]").sortable({
   cursor: 'move',
   helper: fixHelperModified,    
   revert: true,
   items: "[id*=container] [id*=dataTbl] tbody tr:not(.placeholder)",                
   receive: function (event, ui) {                    
      var grid = $IG.WebDataGrid.find("destinationGrid");                   
      $sentence = $(ui.item).find("td").eq(0).html();
      var row = new Array(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1), $sentence, $order);
      grid.get_rows().add(row);                  
  }
});
```

The problem is: When I drop items from the sourceGrid to the destinationGrid, I don't want the draggable to be placed into the new Grid - I only want to use the receive function to create a new row in the grid with the values from the draggable element. Right now, I get both - the newly created gridRow and the dropped item. How can I prevent that?

Comment: What have you tried? How about changing the "helper" method to *original* and then `remove()` on drop?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. I Need the 'clone' behaviour. I don't want to move, but clone the items from the source to the Destination and still have them in the source. When I `remove()` the ui.item in the receive Event, I delete the original row in the sourceGrid. This behaviour is totally weird, I don't understand why ui.item is the original element that I dragged, and not the cloned placeholder.

Comment: Have you tried making your `sourceGrid` a *sortable()* as well?  Also, on the `receive` event, can you console.log the *ui.helper*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the copied item in the beforeStop event.

```
var newItem;

$(".list").sortable({
  connectWith: ".list",
  beforeStop: function (event, ui) { 
      newItem = ui.item;
  },
  receive: function(event,ui) {
      $(newItem).doSomething();
  }
});​
```

Reference and credit to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864644/3523694